# How to use multiple USB webcam in Matlab working simultaneously?

Tags: matlab, webcam

I would like to take the live video with two USB webcams (Philips SPC 900NC), but I found that they cannot work simultaneously on my laptop. Either of the two USB webcams could work alone or work with another webcam (mounted on my laptop originally).

When I use the simulink block 'From video device', Matlab gave the error message with ' Multiple VIDEOINPUT objects cannot access the same device simultaneously.'. Then I checked the video input device with command 'imaqhwinfo', only one of the USB Philips webcam could be detected.

I would like to know that,

1. what's the reason of this situation? is it because the hardware limitation (USB bus bandwidth) or just matlab video object don't support same multiple video devices?
2. what's the solution of this? could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

You may interest in this link:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#How_to_use_2_cameras_.28multiple_cameras.29_with_cvCam_library

Which contains:

First, init the cvcam library and get the number of cams by:

```
int ncams = cvcamGetCamerasCount( );    //returns the number of available cameras in the system
```

Show dialog to choose which cameras in use

```
int* out; int nselected = cvcamSelectCamera(&out);
```

Get the selected cams and enable them.

```
int cam1 = out[0];
int cam2 = out[1];

cvcamSetProperty(cam1, CVCAM_PROP_ENABLE, CVCAMTRUE);
cvcamSetProperty(cam1, CVCAM_PROP_RENDER, CVCAMTRUE);  //We'll render stream from this source
cvNamedWindow("Cam1", 1);
cvcamWindow MyWin1 = (cvcamWindow)cvGetWindowHandle("Cam1");
cvcamSetProperty(cam1, CVCAM_PROP_WINDOW, &MyWin1);   // Selects a window for  video rendering
//Same code for camera 2
cvcamSetProperty(cam2, CVCAM_PROP_ENABLE, CVCAMTRUE);
cvcamSetProperty(cam2, CVCAM_PROP_RENDER, CVCAMTRUE);
cvNamedWindow("Cam2", 1);
cvcamWindow MyWin2 = (cvcamWindow)cvGetWindowHandle("Cam2");
cvcamSetProperty(cam2, CVCAM_PROP_WINDOW, &MyWin1);

//If you want to open the property dialog for setting the video format parameters, uncomment this line
//cvcamGetProperty(cam1, CVCAM_VIDEOFORMAT, NULL);
//cvcamGetProperty(cam2, CVCAM_VIDEOFORMAT, NULL);
```

Enable the stereo mode (2 cameras working at the same time)

```
cvcamSetProperty(cam1, CVCAM_STEREO_CALLBACK , stereocallback); //stereocallback is the function running to process every frames

cvcamInit();
cvcamStart();

//Your app is working
while (1)
{
     int key = cvWaitKey(5);
     if (key == 27) break;
}
cvcamStop( );
cvcamExit( );
```

Define the stereocallback function outside of the function above.

```
void stereocallback(IplImage* image1, IplImage* image2) {

//Process 2 images here
}
```